# Hair particle orientation flips when responding to wind

Tags: particles, hair, force-fields

I am trying to set up a scene with grass modelled as a hair particle system which responds to a wind field. The grass moves in the wind just fine, but as the strength of the wind changes from positive to negative, the orientation of the grass objects flips.

Here is the orientation with a positive wind strength:
[image]

Here is the orientation with a negative wind strength:
[image]

As the sign of the strength changes, the hairs seem to instantaneously rotate 180 degrees about z.

Here is an example .blend file: [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/vrauz8cuw2h90qn/badgrass.blend?dl=0)

The problem seems to be that the orientation of the hair is controlled by the wind - rotating the wind about z clearly shows this. Note, that the 'affect rotation' setting is unchecked in this example:
[image]

Any help greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Honestly, I don't know why this flipping happens. But you can use the ***Particle Instance* modifier** instead of the *Rendered as Object* method. The advantage is that the grass does not flip and it can bend in the direction of the wind (and not to the left or right).

To use the ***Particle Instance* modifier** method to the following:

- in the *Particle Settings* of the *Grass* (plane) **reset** the *Render > Render As* value to `Path`
- select the grass blade (*Plane.003*), and **move it to the world origin** with <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> *& Selection to Cursor* (make sure the 3D Cursor is at world origin like in the uploaded blend file)
- in *Edit* mode, **straighten the grass blade**. Then in *Object* mode, **apply the *Scale*** to the object with <kbd>Ctrlt</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> *& Scale*. Just to note, it's important that *Scale*, *Rotation* and *Location* are applied and object's origin is at world origin. This should be now the case:
  [image: blade of grass]
- add a *Particle Instance* modifier, move it up before the *Solidify* modifer, and select the *Grass* (plane) object + *ParticleSystem* and tick the `[X]` *Create Along Path* checkbox: 
  [image: modifier stack]

The result should look like this:
[image: grass in the wind part 1]

Now the grass bends in the right direction and does no longer flip direction but it twitches in the wind when the animation runs. To get rid of this behavior and to add more realism you can **enable** `[X]` **Hair Dynamics** in the *Particle Settings* of the *Grass* plane and adjust a few settings:

- set *Hair Dynamics > Structure > Vertex Mass* to `0.1 kg`. This influences the inertia
- set *Hair Dynamics > Structure > Stiffness* to `2.500`
- and reset *Field Weights > Wind* to `1.000` so the wind has full influence again.
- if the grass blade looks blocky then increase the *Viewport Display > Strand Steps*. There is also an equivalent setting for the render (*Render > Path > Steps*).

Final result:
[image: final result animation]

**Variations**

The *Particle Instance* modifier lets you randomize the rotation, and size. The two *Layers* which are vertex colors can be used in the material shader to change to color or texture mapping.

For a completely different geometry, you need to create a new model and add another particle system. Unfortunately, it is not possible to specify a collection with multiple objects as in the *Render As* method.

[image: variations]

Comment: Perfect, thank you very much. Is it possible to instance a collection, as one can when using a particle system directly ('render as collection')?

Comment: That's a good point. Unfortunately, it's not possible to instance a collection (or at least I don't know ;-) If you want to add flowers for example you need another particle system, weight paint if you like, and a flower model. But the color, texture, size, and rotation can be randomized. I've added this info to the answer above.