# Flickering/ Particle Hair in Blender

Tags: particles

I am pretty new to Blender and I am trying to control particle hair.
I want it to look like it's floating and waving under water. I tried out the hair dynamics,
all the different forces to no satisfying result -_-

Here's what i got:
https://youtu.be/G3tXK6CeZSw

-World Gravity is disabled
-No Force Fields

-See the rest of the settings of the particle system in the Screenshots
And what's worse is these little jitter movements the Hair is doing...

Can anyone help me with this?
How to get rid of this flickering/jittering?
How to get control over the hairs motion?

Best Regards

Curb

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Hello and welcome! Please add more information, screenshots, or an example file. It's not possible to answer this question without wild guessings. We don't know what you have done. We only see the short video clip that shows the current result. The particle system has a lot of settings and options. Which one have you used? Have you used force fields? Wind? Have a look here for a grass+wind setup: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/235050/107598

Comment: @Blunder Thanks for the fast reply. I edited my comment. I'll check out the link you provided me =)

Comment: please add blend file